# Symfony deployement with heroku

Tags: php, symfony, heroku

I tried to deploy my first app using heroku. I followed all tutorials on heroku how to set routing, added pgsql addon to my app, but when I try to register new user I get

`The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".`

and Logged error

`{"message":"Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\ConnectionException: \"An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] connection to server at \"127.0.0.1\", port 5432 failed: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?\" at /app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/API/PostgreSQL/ExceptionConverter.php line 81","context"`

Routing seems to work fine, but when I try to connect to db to create user an error occurs.

Comment: Looks like either the host IP and/or port are wrong, or that the postgres sever isn't running. Have you verified those?

Comment: Okay, I resolved my problem. 1st of all I had to add DATABASE_URL to config vars, while adding DB new var was added "HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ONYX_URL" I thought it'll somehow replace DATABASE_URL automatically but it didn't.